# On refresh angular params are empty and it's not taking the current query param values

Tags: angular, angular-routing, reload, angular-activatedroute

I have queryparams with some values. If i did any changes in the form the changedvalue is coming in the urlbar.refreshquery param is getting empty.changed value is not coming.

I tried with activatedroute.queryparams.subscribe in ngoninit(). First time its empty. 2nd time its not taking current query param

Comment: please show your code so we can see the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.